Alternative way to turn on/off video of HDMI and DP cables
I want to be able to turn on and off the video of HDMI and DP cables (male to female) coming out of my PC/GPU with esp32 powered by my PC USB.
For HDMI I used pin 1 and I control it with relay that controlled by ESP32.
For DisplayPort I used pin 18 that is controlled by another relay.
I wonder if it is safe to do and if there is alternative to two relays.
Edit: I added circuit image but I'm not sure why. My question is more about the cables side and how to control them. Before downvoting please let me know what was not understandable so I can fix it.


We don't know how you are controlling them to assess if it is safe or not. Please draw schematics.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Both HDMI and DP are multi-core cables.  Which signals were you planning on disconnedting?

@SimonB I tried the wires that are "free" and not twisted in separate shield. For HDMI I found pin 1 and for DP pin 18. Both was able to turn on and off the video on my monitor on runtime.

Looking at the HDMI pinout, pin 1 is TDMS Data 2+.  I can imagine that disconnecting one of the data pins would block the signal.  But if you're sending the 2+ signal through a relay, but not the 2- signal, then skew could easily become a problem.  If so, the whole thing could be quite unreliable.
Edit after comment below, was it really the Data 2+ pin, or the Hot Plug pin?  Disconnecting that would make the device appear not to be plugged in.
You may not have the same problems with DisplayPort pin 18.

Like OP said, the wires that were not twisted in separare shield. Therefore it's impossible OP means pin 1 which is a high speed data lane, surely a twisted pair with separate foil shield. However, the other end of the connector happens to be pin 19 which is Hotplug Detect. For generic cheap cables it will be a single unpaired wire, but with modern cables that support ARC, it will also  be one wire in a twisted pair.

I'm sorry guys, you are correct it was pin 19. It is a generic Aliexpress wire. I'm really not sure how I made this mistake. the DisplayPort pin is correct.

I wonder if there is an alternative. the HDMI and DisplayPort will be synced. I believe I can't simply connect both HPD wires together.
